# Why do some TeX documents not use links in TOC?

Tags: links, documentation

I really love LaTeX (or TeX - I don't really know the difference. I only know that LaTeX is a superset of TeX). One reason why I like it is the automatic creation of links within a PDF document. I think this really adds value to the document as it is much easier to read online this way.

But I've just seen some books / documents written with (La)TeX, that don't have a linked TOC:

- The TeXbook
- `amsmath` documentation (`amssym` does not even have a PDF documentation … or at least there appears only text when I type `texdoc amssym`)
- (I'm quite sure there were more, but every package I've just tried had links. So maybe I just had bad luck?)

Is there any reason for this? Were links added with LaTeX (was pdftex part of TeX?) and is this the reason why some documents don't have links?

Is there any reason not to update those documents? (I guess a reason for not updating the TeX-book might be the aim for an ultra-stable document, but why isn't `amsmath` updated?)

Comment: Because some use [hyperref](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref), some don't. I am not sure whether such a system exists for TeX. And The TeX-Book was written using pure TeX. Using, or not using `hyperref` depends simply on the free-will of the user, unless mandated.

Comment: Note that it is _not permitted_ to create a PDF (or any other typeset form) of _The TeXbook_ without permission from the publisher. The only legitimate form of the typeset book is in print, so links are not required. (The source of the book is available as a demonstration of how to use TeX.)

Comment: @JosephWright: Interesting. I was not aware of that. Does something similar also apply to the documentation of `amsmath`?

Comment: If I may chime in—I have no idea if `amsmath` has similar licensing. I suspect it does not, but it would not surprise me if the `amsmath` documentation were written in raw TeX, making hyperlinking more difficult.  (It certainly wasn't created with DocTeX…)

Comment: @seanAllred the source of the amsmath documentation (amsldoc) is on CTAN and probably in your tex system. It is a rather normal latex document and you can simply add hyperref and recompile to get a version with links.

Comment: It should perhaps be noted that the latex system is older than the web (and older than the internet being in the UK at least).

Comment: @JosephWright, the source of the book is available? Where? I'd like to see some macros to typeset codes.

Comment: @moose the restriction on the texbook is not (just) tucked away in some obscure licence text, if you try to process it with tex you get an error message: `! This manual is copyrighted and should not be TeXed. \body ...` so anyone who has produced a pdf file from the source has gone in and edited the file to remove that error message, which you can hardly do by accident.

Comment: @Sigur type texbook.tex into google:-) (it's on ctan)

Comment: @SeanAllred -- the documentation for `amsmath`, `amsfonts`, et al., was written before there was a really viable version of `hyperref`.  when these packages are updated (long awaited, but not yet firmly scheduled), addition of hyperlinks in the documentation is high on the list.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Good to know!

Comment: I don't use any kind of links in my documents, mostly because they are aimed only for printing. `:)`

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps a direct answer for *why*:

> Because TeX was created to publish books, not PDFs, and books don't have links.

As the comments have pointed out, the only difference here is that those PDFs which *are* hyperlinked throughout generally load the `hyperref` package (or equivalents).

Answer (score 4):

The table of contents becomes hyperlinked if you add

```
\usepackage{hyperref}
```

to your document. This is for LaTeX, it is not available for Plain TeX. So it's very hard to get hyperlinks into a Plain TeX document, such as the TeXBook.

As for package documentations and other documents, it is completely the author's decision whether to include `hyperref` or not.

Comment: You can do links in plain, it's just more work (or at least not as trivial as with `hyperref`)

Comment: @JosephWright `eplain` has some support for hyperlinks.

Answer (score 0):

The answer was already given in the comments, so lets sum it up using a community wiki answer (feel free to add/modify reasons):

- **TeX is older than the Web**: TeX was created 1977, first drafts for the World Wide Web were created in 1989 (although the idea of (hyper)links is older, it was for sure not that common)

  - The `amsmath`-package is old. According to [barbara beeton](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/579/barbara-beeton) it is planned to add hyperlinks to the documentation in a feature release.
- **Some TeX-books use only TeX, not LaTeX**: According to [Joseph Wright](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/73/joseph-wright) and [egreg](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/4427/egreg) it is possible to create links with pure TeX, I'm pretty sure it is much more difficult than using [`hyperref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref). And there is a [reason to use plain TeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/7283/5645).
- **For TeXbook: Licensing**: It is not permitted to create a PDF of the TeXbook