# Coloured text in plain tex

Tags: color, plain-tex

Recently I became intrigued by plain TeX because it gives even more flexibility than regular LaTeX.

In my document I wish to use grayscales of text. In LaTeX, producing this result is achieved through the `color` package. `texdoc color` gives great documentation on the `graphics` bundle by David Carlisle, but extensive documentation on the implementation is missing.

Alternatively I could try working my way through `xcolor` which is substantially more complex when it comes to its implementation, but behold, a complete chapter on the implementation is missing in that package too.

I've found some workarounds on the `comp.text.tex` forums (http://compgroups.net/comp.text.tex/problem-using-color-and-graphicx-in-plain-tex/1918061), which is of course very *easy* and (if you will) *convenient*, but these solutions conflict at its heart with the primary reason as outlined in [Reasons to use plain TeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7278/reasons-to-use-plain-tex), namely that the plain TeX format is not affected by the sands of time. Using a LaTeX package in a plain TeX document could possibly be argued to touch on a gray area, e.g. "the `color` package is unlikely to change in the near future". However, from my vantage point, the purpose of this question could stretch even further, giving an outline of implementation of an interlocking between a graphical driver (which I assume is at play in the `color` package and related packages) and TeX.

So I would like to ask about the implementation of the `color` package in plain TeX, or an alternative implementation with similar functionality.

Comment: First sentence is false of course:-)

Comment: The latex `graphics` and `color` packages may be used in plain tex. http://www.ctan.org/pkg/miniltx

Comment: First sentence is true of course:-)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As the question is focussed on learning how these things may be done just using the primitives (I'd agree with [David's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/207287) that loading the `color` package in plain is an easier route).

What I'll do here is implement much the same approach as is taken by the `color` package, with appropriate tests for classical TeX (`dvips` or `dvipdfm(x)` drivers), pdfTeX/LuaTeX in PDF mode and XeTeX. As there is a bit going on, I'll intersperse the code with comments.

First, set up a conditional to test for direct PDF output

```
\newif\ifpdfmode

\begingroup\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\endgroup
\expandafter\ifx\csname pdfoutput\endcsname\relax
\else
  \ifnum\pdfoutput>0 %
    \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\pdfmodetrue
  \fi
\fi
```

Define the current colour as black, using an `\edef` so that once defined there are no conditionals about (the same idea applies to the rest of the code)

```
\edef\currentcolor{%
  \ifpdfmode
    0 g 0 G%
  \else
    gray 0%
  \fi
}
```

Set up a pre-defined colour: I've just done one (red) as a demo:

```
\edef\colorred{%
  \ifpdfmode
    1 0 0 rg 1 0 0 RG%
  \else
    rgb 1 0 0%
  \fi
}
```

For direct PDF output, there may be a colour stack available (since pdfTeX 1.40.0). A one-off test will tell us this: if there is no stack, just restore the colour manually. See the pdfTeX manual for the details here.

```
\begingroup\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\endgroup
\expandafter\ifx\csname pdfcolorstack\endcsname\relax
  \ifpdfmode
    \def\pdfcolorstackpush{\pdfliteral{\currentcolor}}%
    \let\pdfcolorstackpop\pdfcolorstackpush
  \fi
\else
  \chardef\colorstack=0 %
  \def\pdfcolorstackpush{%
    \pdfcolorstack\colorstackcnt push{\currentcolor}%
  }%
  \def\pdfcolorstackpop{%
    \pdfcolorstack\colorstackcnt pop\relax%
  }%
\fi
```

The main macro to set colour starts with a test: if the argument is the name of a pre-defined colour use that, otherwise assume a hard-coded engine-specific value. (A more sophisticated approach is to convert the colour to the correct format: as that is not asked for in the question I'll leave as an exercise). Once the colour is set up, insert the appropriate special (noting the `\edef` will again mean at point of use there are no conditionals):

```
\edef\color#1{%
  \begingroup\noexpand\expandafter\noexpand\expandafter\noexpand\expandafter\endgroup
  \noexpand\expandafter\noexpand\ifx\noexpand\csname color#1\noexpand\endcsname\relax
    \def\noexpand\currentcolor{#1}%
  \noexpand\else
    \noexpand\expandafter\let\noexpand\expandafter\noexpand\currentcolor
      \noexpand\csname color#1\noexpand\endcsname
  \noexpand\fi
  \ifpdfmode
    \noexpand\pdfcolorstackpush
  \else
    \special{color push \noexpand\currentcolor}%
  \fi
  \aftergroup\noexpand\resetcolor
}
```

Following the `color` approach, a reset macro is also created using the appropriate special.

```
\edef\resetcolor{%
  \ifpdfmode
    \noexpand\pdfcolorstackpop
  \else
    \special{color pop}%
  \fi
}
```

The demo itself. The implementation above relies on a level of grouping inside boxes, which in LaTeX would be done by the `\savebox` 'wrapper' for `\hbox` (and so on). In plain that's not the case, so a colour-safe box needs a group. This could of course be put inside an appropriate set of wrapper macros:

```
\newbox\mybox
\setbox\mybox=\hbox{\begingroup\color{red}Red text\endgroup}
Surrounding text \box\mybox \space and more of it.
\bye
```

(Note: I've constructed the above in much the same way as I'd do using DocStrip for creating separate files. As DocStrip is not involved, this costs of some conditional/`edef` work.)

Comment: The above is more-or-less a direct copy of `color` or indeed the same implementation in `l3drivers`.

Comment: Note that other colour models can be covered: conversion code is present in the `color` package, but again that's probably an exercise here.

Comment: As noted in the other answers, this code is not really the tricky part: it's the entire 'don't colour stuff by accident' business you need to worry about!

Comment: There is an unwanted space generated in horizontal mode because of space after `\pdfcolorstack\colorstackcnt pop`. And another mistake: the `\colorstackcnt` is uninitialized. It means that it is zero.

Comment: @wipet I wasn't 100% sure if a space was needed after the keyword here, so had included one 'to be safe': I'd not tested fully. I'd not checked the full detail of the colour stack business, so was assuming it just required an integer: I've modified.

Comment: I have no experiences with `\pdfcolorstack` but I see that the unwanted space disapears after remowing space after `pop`. The pdfTeX documentation is misty because it mentions the "general text" for all usage of `\pdfcolorstack` but the experiences show that it is not true.

Comment: @wipet Indeed: I'd agree this one is far from clear in the docs. I'm not even sure it's tied to PDF mode, as unlike some other primitives added by pdfTeX it's defined in DVI mode too (no idea what it does there or how that would interact with `\special`s!).

Comment: @JosephWright The `\pdfcolorstack` stuff is tied to PDF mode, because pdfTeX also contains the PDF output driver part, which handles the different color stacks. I don't think, there is a DVI driver that can handle more than one color stack.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek Is somebody able to explain me why the question `\ifx\pdfoutput\undefined` is written here by 4x`\expandafter`, `\begingroup`, `\csname` etc.? I fully understand this code but it seems to me totally redundant. And the `\ifnum\csname pdfoutput\endcsname>0` seems to me as nonsens. Plain TeX users do things simple.

Comment: @wipet If someone has done `\expandafter\ifx\csname pdfouput\endcsname\relax` then `\pdfouput` will exist even if it's not the primitive. Thus the `\begingroup\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\endgroup` construct is used to test that the name exists and is not equal to `\relax` and to avoid adding anything to the hash table after the test.

Comment: @wipet I could probably not bother with `\ifnum\csname pdfoutput\endcsname>0`: I tend to be vary wary of including any tokens which may not be defined in my code at all if I can, and the `\csname` construct ensures this.

Comment: @wipet Just because the example is for plain doesn't mean that there is not a `\input some-macro-bundle` line before it's used which could do anything.

Comment: Yes. It is a raw path to the bad programming style. Normal TeX programmer never write such nonsens as `\expandafter\ifx\csname pdfouput\endcsname\relax`. We are in plain TeX here and we can suppose that there are normal TeX programmers. If somebody does such nonsenses then it is his/her problem.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek Reasonable point. What's odd is that pdfTeX defines the primitive at all in DVI mode: usually if they are only applicable when creating PDFs they are not available otherwise.

Comment: If `\pdfoutput` isn't defined then `\ifnum\relax>0` crashes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17942/discussion-between-joseph-wright-and-wipet).

Answer (score 14):

The latex `graphics` and `color` packages may be used in plain tex. http://www.ctan.org/pkg/miniltx

The maintainers of `texdoc` have chosen to show `grfguide.pdf` for `texdoc color` If you go `texdoc color.pdf` then you get the color package documentation, including fully indexed source listings.

plain tex has some virtues in being a simple format useful for teaching how to build a format, but I can't really imagine any way in which it could be said to be more flexible than latex. LaTeX doesn't remove any functionality.

Comment: "The `\magnification` command of Plain TeX has no counterpart in LaTeX" -L. Lamport, p.205 LaTeX User Guide and Reference Manual.  I'm just tweaking you ;^)

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes You shouldn't believe everything you read

Comment: Mayhaps I should have mentioned I used the broader definition of flexibility here. If the user knows how to build a format, then accessibility to certain flexibility is greatly improved. What I mean with this is that when the user has a better understanding of the low-level parts of the code, that will enhance control over the final print.

Comment: @1010011010 perhaps, do you think if a user understands x86 machine code they have a better understanding of the C++ in the source of a web browser, and that the stability and maintainability of the system would be improved if assembler was injected in at random places?

Comment: @1010011010 For `color` the main part of the work was not the color package itself it was going through the entire format and making sure all box access was "color safe" with extra groups to ensure that colour changes were correctly scoped. Even if you did the same for plain.tex it wouldn't really help as you can't control box assignements that users make. A major advantage in using a defined API above the bottom level (in any language) is that the access functions can be redefined, so for latex it should  be enough to make the kernel colour safe and the latex `\sbox` command

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes I have successfully used `\mag` (not `\magnification`) with LaTeX several times. ;-) Now, knowing what `\magnification` does needs a look at Appendix B in the TeXbook to discover that `\mag` is the primitive involved; and using `\mag` in LaTeX exposes to similar risks as injecting Assembler in C++. One can use it and enjoy it, but *many* things can go wrong.

Answer (score 8):

I've implemented full color stuff in my OPmac package for plainTeX. So I know, where are problems.

You can put the color selector to the typesetting material simply using `\pdfliteral` or `\special` but you have to keep in mind that the color is changed from this point to the end of page independent on grouping / paragraphs etc. from TeX point of view. For example `\pdfliteral{1 0 0 r}` means that all the text from this point to the end of the page (including footline, page number etc.) is red and the next page is reinitialized black. If you print something in the box which cannot break to more pages, then the

```
\hbox{\pdfliteral{1 0 0 r}Something in red\pdfliteral{0 g}}
```

is sufficient. But if the color can break into more pages or if you need the color stack (i.e the possibility to return to the previous color -- no explicitly Black) then you have to correct the headline/footline in `\plainoutput` and you have to implement color managing system over pages, managing colors stack etc. Moreover, there are two types of color selectors in PDF: for strokes and for fills. You can manage them independently or set both to the same color everywhere.

I've described all these features from implementation point of view in my technical documantation for OPmac: `opmac-d.pdf`, but it is only in Czech, sorry.

Comment: This sounds really good. Is there anything planned for an English translation of the documentation?

Comment: If you are using pdfTeX, wouldn't you normally want the colour stack active in your example (assuming a recent enough pdfTeX)? (`\pdfcolorstack <number> push <current colour>` and so on.)

Comment: @1010011010 I have a lot of plans:). English translation is between them. Maybe students in my course will help me. English isn't my hobby.

Comment: @JosephWright I know `\pdfcolorstack` primitve. But OPmac doesn't use it because macros here are older than this primitive. Macro in OPmac implements its own color stack. The documentation about `\pdfcolorstack` was missing until 2013.

Comment: @wipet Yes, sure, I understand that would have been the case when it was developed but I meant that for a solution today you would naturally use the stack if available.

Comment: @JosephWright I agree with you. I never wrote that `\pdfcolorstack` is not suitable for usage.

Answer (score 7):

I tried to rewrite macros written by Joseph Wright in order they are more readable. His macros are less legible because of 1) redundant expandafters, begingroups csnames etc. when testing of the existence of the primitives and 2) usage of `\edef` for two variants of macros instead of usage of `\ifpdfmode` only once.

The comments are the same as in the Josephs answer.

```
\newif\ifpdfmode

\ifx\pdfoutput\undefined
\else
  \ifnum\pdfoutput>0 \pdfmodetrue
  \fi
\fi

\ifpdfmode

\def\colorblack   {0 g 0 G}
\def\colorred     {1 0 0 rg 1 0 0 RG}
\def\colorgreen   {0 1 0 rg 0 1 0 RG}
\def\colorblue    {0 0 1 rg 0 0 1 RG}

\ifx\pdfcolorstack\undefined
  \def\pdfcolorstackpush{\pdfliteral{\currentcolor}}
  \let\pdfcolorstackpop\pdfcolorstackpush
\else
  \mathchardef\colorstackcnt=\pdfcolorstackinit page {\colorblack}
  \def\pdfcolorstackpush{\pdfcolorstack\colorstackcnt push{\currentcolor}}
  \def\pdfcolorstackpop{\pdfcolorstack\colorstackcnt pop}
\fi

\else % of \ifpdfmode

\def\colorblack   {gray 0}
\def\colorred     {rgb 1 0 0}
\def\colorgreen   {rgb 0 1 0}
\def\colorblue    {rgb 0 0 1}

\def\pdfcolorstackpush{\special{color push \currentcolor}}
\def\pdfcolorstackpop{\special{color pop}}

\fi  % of \ifpdfmode

\def\color#1{\expandafter
  \ifx\csname color#1\endcsname \relax \def\currentcolor{#1}%
  \else \edef\currentcolor{\csname color#1\endcsname}%
  \fi
  \pdfcolorstackpush  
  \aftergroup\pdfcolorstackpop
}
\let\currentcolor=\colorblack
```

We need to set the pagenumber to black, if the color breaks to more pages:

```
\footline={\color{black}\hss\tenrm\folio\hss}
```

And the test:

```
Surrounding text {\color{red}Red text} and more of it.

Text {\color{blue}text
     {\color{green}gree gr ee g re eg re
     \vfil\break 
     egrg ree g reeg ree greeg grr reeg ree gre eee
     green text} textik} end.

\bye
```

**Edit** My first advice about making pagenumber black was only a simple introduction to the new problem. Now, we can remove the line `\footline=...` from our code and we will do things more conceptual.

We need to redefine `\plainoutput` in order to the `\headline`, `\footline` `\topins` and `\footins` are initialized by black color at every page. To do this, we set `\currentcolor` to `\colorblack` locally in output routine and we need to surround the `\makeheadline`, `\makefooline`, `\unvbox\topins` and `\footnoterule\unvbox\footins` by `\pdfcolorstackpush`, `\pdfcolorstackpop` pair. It means the following redefinition:

```
\def\plainoutput{%
  \let\currentcolor=\colorblack
  \shipout\vbox{\pdfcolorstackpush\makeheadline\pdfcolorstackpop
                \pagebody
                \pdfcolorstackpush\makefootline\pdfcolorstackpop}%
  \advancepageno
  \ifnum\outputpenalty>-20000 \else\dosupereject\fi
}    
\def\pagecontents{%
  \ifvoid\topins\else\pdfcolorstackpush\unvbox\topins\pdfcolorstackpop\fi
  \dimen0=\dp255 \unvbox255
  \ifvoid\footins\else 
    \vskip\skip\footins
    \pdfcolorstackpush\footnoterule
    \unvbox\footins\pdfcolorstackpop\fi
  \csname ifr@ggedbottom\endcsname \kern-\dimen0 \vfil \fi
}
```

**Note** The synchronization of color stack with TeX grouping mechanism is implemented via `\aftergroup` and this is sometimes fragile. Joseph mentioned that the problem is in `\setbox=\hbox{...\aftergroup\token...}` because the `\aftergroup` token is  processed after the box is set thus the `\pdfcolorstackpop` is inserted into the material where `\setbox` is used and not inside the `\hbox`. Thus we need to write

```
\setbox0=\hbox{{\color{red}text}}
```

The second example, where it is fragile, is `\footnote*{\color{green}text}` but you can re-define `\footnote` to make things more comfortable for user.

**Note2** PDFTeX offers more than one stack and PDF specification gives two types of color selectors: `1 0 0 r` for fills and `1 0 0 R` for strokes. The example above uses both selectors in parallel (like in `color.sty`) but we can initialize second independent color stack for the second color selector and give to the user the possibility to select the right color selector (for text or for lines) like OPmac does it. But the problem is here: there are no more independent color stacks when `xdvipdfmx` is used. And the implementation of two independent color stacks at macro level is slightly more complicated (OPmac does this because its macros are older than `\pdfcolorstack` primitive).

Comment: `\folio` is a new command in your most recent adaptation. Could elaborate on its functionality in your post?

Comment: @1010011010 I don't understand your comment. `\folio` is defined in plain TeX an I've tried the code from my post in plain TeX and without problems. The original content of `\footline` was changed only by adding `\color{black}`.

Comment: @wipet You need `\begingroup\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\endgroup\ifx\csname color#1\endcsname` to avoid adding various `\color...` names to the hash table and equal to `\relax` for undefined colours.