# plain tex: justify text after raggedright

Tags: horizontal-alignment, plain-tex

I have played around with plain `tex` for a while now and can't figure out how to get back to justified text after e.g. `\raggedright`. Can it really be that I have to use `\raggedright` in a group `\begingroup\raggedright...\endgroup` in order to restore justified text? There has to be a way to get back the original justifying.

**edit**: I could get something similar to justified texts by using

```
\spaceskip3pt plus 2pt minus 1pt
```

But this is not the original justifying.

Comment: You can use `\show\raggedright` to have TeX stop and show what it is defined as.

Comment: @ShreevatsaR Nice thanks, I wasn't aware of it and checked `plain.tex` for its definition before.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just revert the settings of `\raggedright`.

```
\def\justifying{%
  \rightskip=0pt
  \spaceskip=0pt
  \xspaceskip=0pt
  \relax
}

\raggedright

\input knuth

\justifying

\input knuth

\bye
```

[image]

Comment: +1. Using `\begingroup` and `\endgroup` to surround the ragged-right material doesn't seem to be such a bad idea after all... :-)

Comment: Indeed, but since I am learning, I am trying out things :P Why should I use plain tex nowadays? It's more trying to handle the basics, too.

Comment: @nox, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7278/reasons-to-use-plain-tex