# Driver-dependent invocations of the graphix package?

Tags: graphics, conditionals

The [LaTeX General Guidelines](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/General_Guidelines#The_main_document_document.tex) show a conditional invocation of the `graphicx` package. I wanted to test this out. I did the following:

1. Created a `main.tex` in which I LEFT OUT the big, complicated, conditional header linked above
2. Included a `myplot.pdf` and `myplot.eps` in my working directory.
3. Included a call to `\includegraphics{myplot}` in my `main.tex`.
4. Ran TeXify. `myplot.eps` was plotted as desired.
5. Ran PdfTeXify. `myplot.pdf` was plotted as desired.

Q: Considering that my steps above worked perfectly fine, what's the point of the big, complicated, conditional header?

Q: Do `pdftex` and `dvips` really need to be passed as options to `\documentclass` and `\usepackage{graphicx}`?

Comment: Your method is the approach recommended in the FAQ, see [this answer](http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=graph-pspdf).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This kind of conditional header is outdated (IMHO). I learned it as beginner as well and stopped using it with the same results as you. The `graphicx` package is normally very well capable to detect the output driver by itself. This is in most cases even better than hard coding it.

Because `pdflatex` is nowadays also used for DVI output simply checking for the existence of `\pdfoutput` is not enough anymore.  If you need this use the `ifpdf` package which provides the `\ifpdf` switch. One reason to use it might be to define a different extension list with `\DeclareGraphicsExtensions` for DVI/PS or PDF output. I stopped supporting both formats with my documents years ago. Normally you chose your format in advance and stick with it. IMHO due to the modern *eps-to-pdf* packages there is [not much reason to use DVI output nowadays](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/349/2975).

Also:
The linked document is a wikibook, i.e. everyone can edit it and therefore the quality can vary. Don't pay to much attention to such websites. There is a lot of outdated material on LaTeX in the WWW.

Comment: @Martin: thanks as always for the help. Yes, I suspected this was the case. No complicated headers for me then.

Comment: @brianjd: As always you are very welcome. Please wait before accepting any answers to see what others have to say about this topic.

Comment: What is the best way to rewrite that example on Wikibooks? That is clearly outdated information.

Comment: @Caramdir: Do you mean the way to change it or what content should be on its place? Normally simply creating a Wikibook account should be enough to change it. We could discuss some alternative content on Meta.

Comment: @Martin: What exactly to put in its place.

Comment: Material can be outdated even easier if noone can change it :-)

Comment: @Martin, one reason to maintain a 'bilingual' workflow would be if you're writing an article and want to send a preprint to something like arXiv (which has a very tight size limit, so the better compression of PDF figures is a real help) and also submit to a journal (which often have PS-based workflows).

Comment: @Hendrik: thanks for pointing that out. I was confused as to what that was (thought it meant less than 20% of my posts were accepted without having to be edited :>). Went back and chose accepted answers for almost all my questions.

Comment: @brianjd: Great! (And keep in mind, it's usually good to wait a bit before accepting; other people might come up with better answers.)