# DOI string in ACM Reference Format is running off the page, how to fix it

Tags: doi, acmart

After our paper is accepted, we got the ISBN and DOI information, I fill those information into tex, but the DOI string runs off the page.

I use the 2017 ACM Master Article Template.
Here is the sample code:

```
\documentclass[sigconf]{acmart}

%\usepackage{booktabs} % For formal tables
%\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{balance}  % for  \balance command ON LAST PAGE  (only there!)    
%    \usepackage{subfigure}
%    \usepackage{url}
%    \usepackage{stfloats}
%    \usepackage{amsmath}
%%    \usepackage{mathptmx}
%    \usepackage{color}
%    \usepackage{xcolor}
%    \usepackage{epsfig}
%    \usepackage{endnotes}
%    \usepackage{multirow}
%    \usepackage{amssymb}
%    \usepackage{makecell}
%    \usepackage[ruled,vlined]{algorithm2e}
%    \usepackage{listings}

\copyrightyear{2018} 
\acmYear{2018} 
\setcopyright{rightsretained} 
\acmConference[SIGXXX'18]{2018 International Conference on XXXX XXXX XXXX XXX}{June 11--15, 2018}{YYYYYY, XX, USA}
\acmBooktitle{SIGXXX'18: 2018 International Conference on XXXX XXXX XXXX XXX, June 11--15, 2018, YYYYYY, XX, USA}
\acmDOI{22.3345/3383733.3390659}
\acmISBN{979-2-4403-4702-3/38/06}
...
...
```

After I compiles it, the ACM Reference Format will in pdf will looks like this:
[image]

What's wrong with my tex to make DOI string running off the page?
Is there any way to make DOI string in the next line instead of the same line with other information?

Answer (score 1):

The reason why DOI hyperref is running off the page is I used latex to compile tex instead of pdflatex. It seems that the hyperref package only works well for pdflatex (see [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/349/what-is-the-practical-difference-between-latex-and-pdflatex)).

Two solutions to solve this problem:

1. If you still want to use latex, import ***breakurl*** package.
2. Switch to pdflatex to compile the tex